# Margin call/maintenance question

Tags: margin, margin-call

I am now facing a margin call, and I have a question,

- Bought a stock at $x on %50 margin maintenance
- After Jan 28, the stock dropped, and my margin maintenance increased to 100%
- It says I need to deposit about 50k to resolve the account deficit
- I want to HOLD this stock long term now and no

Answer (score 1):

Seems  like an unfinished question...

A margin call is a margin call.  You either meet it or your broker will do whatever  is necessary to bring your account into compliance.

FWIW, 3 margin liquidation violations in a rolling 12-month period will lead to a restricted account.